# In Angular 14, how do I access data passed to a route's "extra.state"?

Tags: angular, routes, state, router, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I want to pass an object to my route so it can be accessed, so I tried

```
this.router.navigate(['start'], { state: product, relativeTo: this.route });
```

How do I access this data subsequently?  In my constructor I tried this

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ...
  ) {
    ...
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state) {
      this.product = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
    }
```

but this results in the compilation error

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#state) it is available as `history.state`.

Comment: 'this.product =  this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.history.state' also results in a compilation error.

Comment: It is not a property of Angular, it is the browser `window.history.state` property.

Comment: This still results in the compilaton error.  FYI, "product" is defined to be "product: Product".

Comment: Did you try to use the `getState` method of the Location Service? import Location from @angular/common module.
inside constructor

`this.product = this.location.getState()`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the data is not so obvious at a first glance. Someone could expect that ActivatedRoute will contain it, but there is no attribute for state. The state property was added to Navigation which is available through Router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state. Problem is that getCurrentNavigation returns Navigation only during the navigation and returns null after the navigation ended. So the Navigationis no longer available in Component’s B onInit lifecycle hook. We need to read the data from browser’s history object:

`history.state`

read more: https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer from just a code fragment but this what has worked for me:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && event?.url === '/start') {
        this.product = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you using Angular 14?  Using your code, "this.product = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;" still produces the compilation error "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'." for me.

Comment: please post how `product` is declared. Likely you need `product: Product | undefined`

Comment: Yes, "product" is defined as "product: Product".  Is there a way to only assign the value if we know the expression is not undefined?  I would prefer not to define my type with "Product | undefined".

Comment: use an if statement

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to answer from just a code fragment, but here is what works for me.

```
constructor(private activatedroute:ActivatedRoute) {}
 
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedroute.data.subscribe(data => {
               console.log(data);
           });
     }
```